# Is there a cap for Sion's Enrage?

Tags: league-of-legends

I just played a game and after getting around 1000 hp I noticed that if I get more cs my max hp does not increase. Is this a bug or a cap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there doesn't seem to be a cap.

[image: There doesn't seem to be a cap.]

Regarding your problem:

> Enrage's health bonus activates only if Enrage is toggled on.

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Sion/Ability_Details

Comment: I can't be that dumb that I switched it off... :D The tooltip is bugged by the way because I can see that my max health increases but the tooltip does not say so. +1 for the nostalgic feelings I got when I saw the good old 3v3 map!!

Comment: This is the only reason I can think of, besides a bug, or Morello's secret ninja nerf.